# Coverting an input string into an interger

Tags: python-3.x, integer, user-input, sentinel

```
#This program calculates the average of integer entered
#Once the use press "S".
#"S" is the sentinel

COUNT= 0
SUM= 0
INT=1
Sentinel = "S"
print('Enter test scores as integers, or enter S to get average.')

INT=input('Enter integer: ')        # input received as a string to allow for the entry of "S"
#Continue processing as long as the user
#does not enter S
while INT!= Sentinel:
    INT=input('Enter integer: ')
    I=int(INT)                      #attempting to format the input(INT) as an integer
    COUNT= + 1
    SUM = COUNT + I
if INT == Sentinel:
    AVRG= SUM/(COUNT-1)
```

I keep getting this error message :
***Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\joshu\Documents\COP100 Python\practice examples\program4-13.py", line 16, in 
I=int(INT)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'***

Comment: You need to check if the input is the sentinel value *before* trying to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Oh like a validation check. Thanks man I'm obviously very new to python I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming that the user will always enter a numeric value.

This line will accept any data entered by the user. It could be numeric or non-numeric.

```
INT=input('Enter integer: ')        # input received as a string to allow for the entry of "S"
```

Before you convert the data into integer, check if the value is numeric. If it is not, then you may want to send an error message back to the user.

```
I=int(INT)                      #attempting to format the input(INT) as an integer
```

You can do that by doing:

```
if INT.isnumeric():
    I = int(INT)
else:
    print ('not a numeric value')
```

I am assuming that users will enter only integers. The above code will work only for integers. If you want to check for floats, then use a `try: except` statement.

Also, your computation of `SUM` to get the average is incorrect. You shouldn't add `COUNT` to `SUM`. You should only add `I` to `SUM` while incrementing `COUNT`.

Also don't try to use variable names as sum, int (even if it is uppercase).

Here's a working code for you to try.

```
count = 0
total = 0
Sentinel = "S"

#Continue processing as long as the user does not enter S
while True:
    test_score = input('Enter test score as integer or enter S to get average: ')
    # input received as a string to allow for the entry of "S"
    
    if test_score.isnumeric():
        score = int(test_score)  #attempting to format the input(INT) as an integer
        count += 1
        total += score
    elif test_score.upper() == Sentinel:
        break
    else:
        print ('Not an integer or S. Please re-enter the value')
if count > 0:
    print (total, count)
    average_score = total/count
    print ('average score is : ', average_score)
else:
    print ('No valid entries were made. Average score is N/A')
```